# Capture groups in mysql regexp

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a table with a varchar column that represents a path. I want to search for rows that have a path that follow a pattern like `name.name[*]` where name can be anything. I am looking for repeated strings contained anywhere in the path column that are separated by a period and have a square bracket after them.

This seems to call for Regexp, so through python I have something like https://regex101.com/r/apS20a/4

However, trying to implement this with MySQL Regexp is not working. I have been able to translate the shorthand into REGEXP '([A-Za-z_]+).(\1[[0-9]+])', but it seems that MySql Regex does not support capture groups. Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do with mysql regexp? Thank you

Comment: I don't think that MySQL regular expressions support that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that MySQL supports capture groups.  But if you only have one example of `.name[` in the string between the first `.` and the first `[`, you can hack your way around it.  This is not a general solution, just a specific approach in this case.

You can get the name with:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(url, '[', 1), '.', -1) as name
```

And then incorporate this into a regular expression:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             substring_index(substring_index(url, '[', 1), '.', -1) as name
      from t
     ) t
where url like concat('%', name, '.', name, '[%');
```

This just uses `like` instead of `regexp`, because `[` and `.` are regular expression wildcards.  Of course, this assumes that name does not have `_` or `%`.

EDIT:

Here is a method that actually identifies when this occurs -- and works even if there are multiple patterns.

The idea is to construct the regular expression based on what happens between the `.` and `[` -- and then to apply it.  Delightfully self-referential:

```
select t.*,
       (url regexp regex)
from (select t.*,
             substr(regexp_replace(url, '[^.]*[.]([^\\[]*)\\[[^.]*', '|$1[.]$1\\\\['), 2) as regex
      from (select 'abcde.de[12345.345[ABC' as url union all
            select 'abcdefdef[[[[..123.124['
           ) t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=16ebc4eaa838ce751169ab0cb016e958) is the above in a db<>fiddle.